# Show, step by step, that $(a * (b * c)) * d = (a * b) * (c * d)$ in any group $(G,*)$.

Tags: group-theory

Show, step by step, that $(a * (b * c)) * d = (a * b) * (c * d)$ in any group $(G,*)$.

It possesses four properties of group:
(i) Identity ($e$): $\forall z\in G, ze = ez = z$,
(ii) Inverse ($z$): $\forall x\in G, \exists y\in G: xy = yx = e$,
(iii) Closure exists wrt $*$ in $G$,
(iv) Associative property holds: $\forall x,y,z \in G, x*(y*z) = (x*y)*z$

$(a * (b * c)) * d = (a * b) * (c * d)$ 
Taking the lhs and as closure is there, so the operation will yield as map an existing element from the four (i.e., $a,b,c,d$).

But, without consulting the group table cannot say what the mapping would be, as no hints are provided.

So, stuck at showing equivalence between the lhs and rhs.:
lhs:$\ (a * (b * c)) * d$ 
rhs:$\ (a * b) * (c * d)$

Comment: All you need for this is Axiom (iv), associativity.

Comment: @DerekHolt You mean to say: $(a*(b*c))*d = ((a*b)*c)*d = ((a*b)*c*d) = (a*b)*(c*d)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider associativity formulated as $\forall x,y,z\in G: x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$. Then

$$(a*(b*c))*d\stackrel{(1)}=a*((b*c)*d)\stackrel{(2)}=a*(b*(c*d))\stackrel{(3)}=(a*b)*(c*d)$$

$(1)$ take $x=a$, $y=b*c$ and $z=d$
$(2)$ take $x=b$, $y=c$ and $z=d$
$(3)$ take $x=a$, $y=b$ and $z=c*d$

Comment: Thanks for using my notation of $x,y,z$ as shown in the associative property.

Comment: @jiten I thought it might be of help for keeping track of what really is going on. Glad to help!

Comment: @Shaun I don't think this change of formatting is necessary.

Comment: Well, to me, it's a little easier to read when things are aligned. Ah well . . .

Comment: @Shaun I understand your point, though, but I don't it's needed, especially given the annotations below.